# Why did the Stack Overflow team decide to use Mercurial for version control?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

According to this [blog post from 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/stack-overflow-and-dvcs/), Stack Exchange is using [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial) for version control for the benefits of collaborative code development.

Why did you decide to use Mercurial over say, [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)?

Comment: It probably had something to do with Fog Creek's Kiln being Mercurial-based.

Comment: Maybe this wasn't true in the past, but Kiln appears to support Git as well as Mercurial now.

Comment: Well, besides that, the initial dev team probably was more comfortable with hg than git due to that influence.

Comment: Most likely because whoever had to decide was too drunk to choose Git. :p

Comment: @ThiefMaster if they were drunk, they would have chosen TFS.

Comment: Associated [joel on software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/03/17.html).

Comment: @ColeJohnson there's drunk and there's **drunk**.