# Why did Stack Exchange source control switch from hg to git?

Tags: discussion

Its clear from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) that the SE team is now using git scm. Previously they used hg according to this [old post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/stack-overflow-and-dvcs/).

I'd like to understand the reasons why the switch was made, because we are evaluating which dvcs to use in our company (also a [WISC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177901/what-does-wisc-stack-mean) shop).

Comment: Proving once again that peer pressure is the deciding factor in version control system choices.

Comment: Related for historical perspective: [Why did the Stack Overflow team decide to use Mercurial for version control?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197606/why-did-the-stack-overflow-team-decide-to-use-mercurial-for-version-control) (notice this was never answered)

Comment: Lol @Shog9 thats what I'm afraid to hear

Comment: Probably because Visual Studio 2013 provide full support for Git, _and_ because Mercurial (with `hg-git` extension) can readily talk with a git back-end, but git has no easy way to talk to a Mercurial back-end.

Comment: Certainly could be reason. They used Visualhg which is a VS plugin and works great. Its not as fancy as git support in 2013, still I'd find it hard to believe if this was only reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was just a matter of convenience. We have [quite a few open source projects in GitHub](https://github.com/stackexchange), and having to continuously switch our development environment from one source control system to the other was not practical.

Other than that, we don't really think that Git is better than Mercurial (or the other way around). Git won by a narrow margin when we reached the "only one survives" point in our discussions on this subject.

Comment: Side note: that actually happened before I joined the team, so I was not present in those discussions.

Comment: Thanks @konamiman appreciate you answering. That was a lot more benign than I was expecting. It definitely makes sense when you think about one toolset to use. I pushed hard for hg at my (now prior) job but it was an uphill battle that I lost. Git has swept  source control, it's pretty much defacto now. I have to say the more I use it the more I like it. Both great software, but heck the one just went viral!